Spring application working when built locally and copied into docker, but not when built inside docker
I'm trying to build and run a Springboot application inside Docker.
At first I would just build the JAR file locally, and then copy and run it in a Docker image, but now I also want to build the JAR file inside docker.
Configuration
package com.qcphotos.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> {
                requests.requestMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/products",
                        "products/parseUrl",
                        "/products/popular",
                        "/products/viewCount"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/affiliates/redirect",
                        "/affiliates/url"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/collections/{collectionId}",
                        "/collections/{collectionId}/products"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/users/{userId}"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/storefronts",
                        "/shippingAgents"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/discord", "/")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        })
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}

Application.yml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          discord:
            client-id: 'myClientId'
            client-secret: 'mySecretCode'
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
              - identify
              - email
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/discord'
            client-name: Discord
        provider:
          discord:
            authorization-uri: https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me
            user-name-attribute: username

Application
package com.qcphotos;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class
})

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

Local build
Dockerfile
I used mvn clean package to create the jar file
FROM openjdk:21
WORKDIR /app
COPY /target/rest-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Result (Working):
https://gist.github.com/Eli-Chandler/288864628eaf4c00a9ca4a78b5ecfe8e
Docker build
Dockerfile
# Build
FROM maven:3.9.7-eclipse-temurin-21 AS build
COPY ./backend /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN mvn clean package

# Run
FROM openjdk:21
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src/rest-api/target/rest-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Result (Not working):
https://gist.github.com/Eli-Chandler/d2cbca5154e39e119d7302abe813d63c

EHrm. jar-with-dependencies feels like you are working around Spring Boot to generate a jar. You should only have the spring-boot-maven-plugin configured, no assembly, jar or whatever pluging to generate a fatjar as spring boot already does that.

@M.Deinum Ah thanks a lot, I changed my build plugin from maven-assembly-plugin to spring-boot-maven-plugin and it works now!
